# use of deleted function 'constexpr class_name& class_name::operator=(const class_name&)'

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, move-constructor

As a beginner challenge exercise I'm trying to implement the following:
Class with an attribute (Vec_ptr_cls): pointer to a vector, methods: constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, destructor and a push_back method, as the pointer is private.
Class with an attribute (Data_cls): pointer to an int, methods: constructor, copy constructor, move constructor and destructor.

Expected result: program compiles, creates new objects of the Data_cls. Creates a new object of the Vec_ptr_cls, pushes back the created Data_cls objects.
Actual result: program does not compile. Error message: use of deleted function 'constexpr Data_cls& Data_cls::operator=(const Data_cls&)'.

I've tried googling it and checking the answers here on StackOverflow, I think either I do not have the required knowledge to make sense of them or they do not apply to this particular case (most of them pertain to const attributes in some class, I have none as far as I understand). I've tried to cut out bits and pieces and it seems that the move constructor for Data_cls is at fault but I cannot understand why or how. The compiler error claims that the copy constructor is deleted, however I've declared my own, shouldn't that be good enough? EDIT: As Nathan Pierson has pointed out, the compiler is actually complaining about the assignment operator, not the copy constructor. I'm even more stumped here.

Here's prototype code to replicate the issue I'm having:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Data_cls
{
private:
    int *d;
public:
    Data_cls(int num)
    {
        d = new int;
        *d = num;
    }

    Data_cls(const Data_cls &source)
    {
        d = new int;
        *d = *source.d;
    }

    Data_cls(Data_cls &&source)
    {
        d = source.d;
        source.d = nullptr;
    }

    ~Data_cls()
    {
        delete d;
    }
};


class Vec_ptr_cls
{
private:
    std::vector <Data_cls> *vec;

public:
    Vec_ptr_cls()
    {
        vec = new std::vector <Data_cls>;
        *vec = {};
    }

    Vec_ptr_cls(const Vec_ptr_cls &source)
    {
        vec = new std::vector <Data_cls>;
        *vec = *source.vec;
    }

    Vec_ptr_cls(Vec_ptr_cls &&source)
    {
        vec = source.vec;
        source.vec = nullptr;
    }

    ~Vec_ptr_cls()
    {
        delete vec;
    }

    void add_new(Data_cls d)
    {
        (*vec).push_back(d);
    }


};

int main()
{

    Data_cls test_d{20};
    Data_cls test_dd{30};
    Data_cls test_ddd{40};

    Vec_ptr_cls tmp_vec{};

    tmp_vec.add_new(test_d);
    tmp_vec.add_new(test_dd);
    tmp_vec.add_new(test_ddd);


    return 0;

}
```

I've encountered this problem while attempting to implement something a bit more complicated (Movie list and Movie object) as an exercise and found it interesting that this does not work even reduced to this bare bones version. I hope my issue is not badly stated, very curious as to why this does not work.

Comment: What is the topic of the chapter in your C++ textbook where this "challenge excersize" is from? Knowing what is the subject matter being learned will help pointing out what the problem is.

Comment: Tangential: `delete[] vec;` in `~Vec_ptr_cls` is incorrect. You didn't use `new[]` to create `vec`, you shouldn't use `delete[]` to destroy it.

Comment: Also the compiler error isn't complaining that the copy _constructor_ is deleted, it's complaining that the copy _assignment operator_ is deleted.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's a general chapter about Classes and objects. The chapter went over constructors, copy constructor and move constructors in there as well (it's a Udemy course from Tim Buchalka). This, without the pointers, was the end of chapter exercise. At the end of the solution video the lecturer left a challenge to remake the whole  exercise with pointers as attributes instead of non-ptr data types.

@NathanPierson Ah, thanks , that's correct, I should have used `delete`. On the assignment operator part, hmm, that's correct, my mistake.

Comment: "**[class.copy.assign]/2** ... If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined as deleted ..." Since you have provided a move constructor for your class, you must also provide a copy assignment operator; and may want to also provide move assignment.

Comment: Google (and follow) the rule of all or none. Define all special member functions or define none of them.

Comment: There is no point whatsoever to allocate a single `int` with `new int`. And only seldomly to allocate a `std::vector` with `new`. But I guess this is just as an exercise.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Alright, do you perhaps know why, if I rewrite this without any pointers but just int and vector, the compiler does not complain at all about the deleted copy assignment operator? I've still declared a move constructor but it does not complain at all.

Comment: Show the example you are asking about. I can't comment on code I can't see.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Nevermind, it does complain about the same thing, I was mistaken. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Igor Tandetnik pointed out this was a case of a missing copy assignment operator, which I did not know existed. Adding this fixed the issue, the program compiles and works as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class Data_cls
{
private:
    int *d;
public:
    Data_cls(int num)
    {
        d = new int;
        *d = num;
    }

    Data_cls(const Data_cls &source)
    {
        d = new int;
        *d = *source.d;
    }

    Data_cls(Data_cls &&source)
    {
        d = source.d;
        source.d = nullptr;
    }


// Added this assignment operator

    Data_cls& operator=(Data_cls other)
    {
        std::swap(d, other.d);
        return *this;
    }

    ~Data_cls()
    {
        delete d;
    }

    void display()
    {
        std::cout << *d;
    }
};


class Vec_ptr_cls
{
private:
    std::vector <Data_cls> *vec;

public:
    Vec_ptr_cls()
    {
        vec = new std::vector <Data_cls>;
        *vec = {};
    }

    Vec_ptr_cls(const Vec_ptr_cls &source)
    {
        vec = new std::vector <Data_cls>;
        *vec = *source.vec;
    }

    Vec_ptr_cls(Vec_ptr_cls &&source)
    {
        vec = source.vec;
        source.vec = nullptr;
    }

    ~Vec_ptr_cls()
    {
        delete vec;
    }

    void add_new(Data_cls d)
    {
        (*vec).push_back(d);
        d.display();
    }

};

int main()
{

    Data_cls test_d{20};
    Data_cls test_dd{30};
    Data_cls test_ddd{40};

    Vec_ptr_cls tmp_vec{};

    tmp_vec.add_new(test_d);
    tmp_vec.add_new(test_dd);
    tmp_vec.add_new(test_ddd);


    return 0;

}
```

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Answers to questions should fully feature a solution. In the case of confirming something worked, I would recommend a comment to the solution that helped you combined with an upvote.

Comment: @user904963 Thanks for the advice, I've added the code with a comment in it. Correct me if I'm wrong, however I think I need 15 rep to upvote comments and this is really my first post on StackOverflow. For me to upvote, the person who solved my issue would have to answer the question instead of me, correct?